# C# Amazon SP API CreateFeedDocument not working

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, rest, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

There are 3 steps to upload a feed via Amazon SP API, the first one is to get feed encryption info via `createFeedDocument` API. But I am getting `Bad Request` as response with following content:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidInput",
      "message": "Invalid Input",
      "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

**C# code**

```
        private async Task<IRestResponse> CreateFeedDocument()
        {
            IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("feeds/2020-09-04/documents", Method.POST);
            restRequest.AddParameter("contentType", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter("MarketplaceIds", "A21TJRUUN4KGV");
            restClient = new RestClient(live_url_base);
            restRequest = await signRequest(restRequest, restClient);
            return restClient.Execute(restRequest);
        }

        private async Task<IRestRequest> signRequest(IRestRequest restRequest, RestClient restClient)
        {
            var roleAcccess = await GetAssumeRoleTokenDetail();
            restRequest.AddHeader("x-amz-access-token", accessToken);

            AWSAuthenticationCredentials AWSCredentials = new AWSAuthenticationCredentials();
            AWSCredentials.AccessKeyId = roleAcccess.Credentials.AccessKeyId;
            AWSCredentials.SecretKey = roleAcccess.Credentials.SecretAccessKey;
            AWSCredentials.Region = region;

            restRequest.AddHeader("X-Amz-Security-Token", roleAcccess.Credentials.SessionToken);
            return new AWSSigV4Signer(AWSCredentials).Sign(restRequest, restClient.BaseUrl.Host);
        }
```

I doubt that I am not using `restRequest.AddParameter` properly, but I am not sure.

I have been following below links:
https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/feeds-api/feeds_2020-09-04.md#createfeeddocument

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide/feeds-api-use-case-guide-2020-09-04.md#step-1-create-a-feed-document

[How to Encrypt and upload data using selling-partner-api in Amzon using .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664197/how-to-encrypt-and-upload-data-using-selling-partner-api-in-amzon-using-net)

**Update**
I also tried replacing below line
`restRequest.AddParameter("contentType", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8", ParameterType.RequestBody);`
with
`restRequest.AddJsonBody(new { contentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" });`

but then I was getting `InvalidSignature` error as below:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/feeds/2020-09-04/documents

host:sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
x-amz-access-token:Atza|IwEBIA5KgrCsBbSXHmrXFS_FIgBTInh_xPAydLfi5q2P9xaFQf7p8Zl4NjqhHHxqRzUku__Q7GN1p2WQGRzuAoAa8oMkPLx57NJ05SqxEVXXG-fet3_XgKj8uBCU30HaGPsKltf4g2MD8Pqqt2OUrOXtkv4dAAjjCIxC-bFwVqOhvHktAur--NBv-bJaPZ608Av1GEu96GsNEV9eb0saVBwLaZD7NW3oOjzlCc8GPV9hdqHV5TUXY77QZgBLD1y94Vs1fSo54ShpyoMMOZebzbSr1K5gtf3wJZ.........................{ I hid it }...........................................
x-amz-date:20210524T175148Z
x-amz-security-token:FwoGZXIvYXdzEGsaDNUytY0xuP5/u61APiK2ARMZgv4IT+y2HLzdg5FjZOv6aL2bJ3baJPxBtCY2/7ASntTXfAF5s39P3/qspLLQfmqHPZiMGjweCE3Yf3aW5Q1mt+FLT2s2VUwuOawOQwDll51T2HB3wqyaDOSEpsWeR2Iym4TJXE2hbo7q5CQQBXissOo1Oruk5gcAp7uQHpnyuhCRCkfv/ErEpzdDA0JqfhMxdzmViVgsL1Kzalnbcy9lp+ACI4TL70iOl6j6xkyhFexe/aLXKLLPr4UGMi3Ver2CL6Q4kz.........................{ I hid it }...........................................

host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token
4d719849acd655844ab5129f5e54a0ed16954c9580c7a9a737504faf42b309e2'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20210524T175148Z
20210524/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request
a20e7ffe252dbf98d6a4b9213511ac1918f8bbad75ccbfd7ec46f5c9c1457b08'
",
     "code": "InvalidSignature"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note**: I have removed some trailing chars of tokens and placed ......{ I hid it }..........

Comment: The GitHub link you posted indicates that [their API consumes JSON](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/feeds-api/feeds_2020-09-04.md#consumes), yet you are trying to use XML it looks like.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: no, that is request body, I am posting below object as json 
`{ "contentType": "application/xml; charset=UTF-8" }`

Comment: I see you add as a query parameter marketpleaceid.  Where did you see that in the documentation, because what their doc shows is just a body parameter.  I've been getting restricted access messages and now wonder if that has been the issue for I do sign the requests.

Comment: did you solve your ploblem? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```cs
restRequest.AddJsonBody("{\"contentType\":\"text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8\"}");

RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://sandbox.sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/");

IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("/feeds/2021-06-30/documents", Method.POST);

restRequest.AddJsonBody("{\"contentType\":\"text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8\"}");
```

Comment: While this is not required, obviously, I would add here *why* this would solve the OP issue and possibly what was wrong with his approach. This would enable better understanding of your solution for others who would come and read it :)

Answer (score 0):

I do that in my open source library and its work without problem

https://github.com/abuzuhri/Amazon-SP-API-CSharp

Here sample to create and submit feed

```
 ConstructFeedService createDocument = new ConstructFeedService("A3J37AJU4O9RHK", "1.02");

        var list = new List<PriceMessage>();
        list.Add(new PriceMessage()
        {
            SKU = "8201031206122...",
            StandardPrice = new StandardPrice()
            {
                currency = BaseCurrencyCode.AED.ToString(),
                Value = (201.0522M).ToString("0.00")
            }
        });
        createDocument.AddPriceMessage(list);

        var xml = createDocument.GetXML();

        var feedID = amazonConnection.Feed.SubmitFeed(xml, FeedType.POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA);

        Thread.Sleep(1000*30);

        var feedOutput=amazonConnection.Feed.GetFeed(feedID);

        var outPut=amazonConnection.Feed.GetFeedDocument(feedOutput.ResultFeedDocumentId);

        var reportOutpit = outPut.Url;
```

Comment: the link is dead. 404...

Answer (score 0):

```
private async Task UploadFile(byte[] bytes, string url)
{
  var contentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"; // this should be the same as what was used in Step #1 (in the CreateFeedDocument API request)

  RestClient restClient = new RestClient(url);
  IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
  restRequest.AddParameter(contentType, bytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);

  var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(restRequest);

  if (!response.IsSuccessful)
  {
    // your error logic
  }

  // success. Move to Step #3
}
```

`IllegalLocationConstraintException`The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.5B8EGG143CSG45XCi7DqESeN8Q/1QfotMvQIiijcEj/76sr2T+gNh9Ubhq5aQZ7SbZMXCIS/8Mgw6iDod2mCwX/LX6Q=